# Gstreamer : relaying a rtsp stream to another windows computer

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

PC1 is connected to a rtsp source via wifi.
PC1 is also connected to another network where PC2 is also connected
both running windows 10

the rtsp source is the RC controller of a drone. (wifi)

on PC 1 I use the following :

C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.43.1:8554/fpv_stream latency=1 udp-reconnect=1 timeout=0 do-retransmission=false ! application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

to play drone's feed.

1. how can I relay the feed from PC1 to PC2 which is not (and cant be) connected to The RC controller?
2. what pipeline can I use to play the feed on PC2? can I use the same?

I have no experience on Gstreamer and I dont know what Im doing.

Thnx in advance.